# Alias a Package to Enable Dual Use Namespaces

Tags: perl, namespaces

I have an interesting situation. In some (large) legacy code, there is a namespace that should look like `require A::B`, but instead the path to A was added so it's possible to just say `require B`. However, I would like to be able to use both invocations. Is this possible without creating a redirecting package? For instance, is there a way to dual declare a package?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I should add I am not using `use` for technical reasons.

Comment: What technical reasons might those be? Do you understand how similar `require` and `use` are?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First load the package:

```
require A::B;
```

Then alias `B` to `A::B`:

```
*B:: = *A::B::;
```

Then tell `require` that it has already loaded `B`

```
$INC{'B.pm'}++;
```

To make sure this all works right, it is best to perform these actions inside a `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {
    require A::B;
    *B:: = *A::B::;
    $INC{'B.pm'}++;
}
```

After this, all `require A::B;` and `require B;` lines will become no-ops.  You will also be able to refer to variables in that package with either name.  `\&A::B::foo == \&B::foo`

To get this to work transparently, you could add the following code to each file:

- `A/B.pm`

  ```
  *B:: = *A::B::;
  $INC{'B.pm'}++;
  ```
- `B.pm`

  ```
  *A::B:: = *B::;
  $INC{'A/B.pm'}++;
  ```

Then if a user does `require A::B;` they can call `A::B::foo` or `B::foo` and `require B;` will become a no-op.

And if a user does `require B;` they can call `A::B::foo` or `B::foo` and `require A::B;` will become a no-op.

But for maintainability, it is probably best to keep all of the real code in one file (along with the aliasing code above), and setup the other file as a shim that just loads the real file.  Assuming `A/B.pm` contains the real code:

- `A/B.pm`

  ```
  *B:: = *A::B::;  # this gets added to the existing file
  $INC{'B.pm'}++;
  ```
- `B.pm`

  ```
  require A::B;  # this is the entire file
  ```

Comment: That took me a while to understand, but very nice.

Answer (score 2):

`require Something` will search the directories in `@INC` for a file called `Something.pm`. 
To get `some-path/A/B.pm` to be loaded with either `require B` or `require A::B`, you would need to have both `some-path` and `some-path/A` in your `@INC` directory list.

There are [many many ways](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq8#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_%28@INC%29_at_runtime?) to add directories or otherwise manipulate your `@INC` list.

Comment: The thing is that that is the current situation, and the require works. Perhaps I should clarify and say that I want to be able to invoke calls to the package both ways as well. `A::B::foo()` and `B::foo()`

Answer (score 1):

Eric's solution would work, but truthfully, I'd shoot anyone who did this in real production code. You could probably achieve similar results by using methods in [Package::Stash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Package%3a%3aStash), but again, why mess up the symbol table like this?  I'd rather fix the legacy code that was calling things the wrong way. Seriously, how hard is it to do a search-and-replace on your code and fix the package names?

Another quick and dirty method to get `require B;` to actually find package A::B is to simply make a symlink in the lib/ directory pointing to A/B.pm:

```
cd lib
ln -sf -T A/B.pm B.pm
```

Note that this will create *two* packages with identical code, so variables in one will *not* be the same value as the other: `$A::B::foo` will be entirely separate from `$B::foo` even though their declaration comes from the same file.

Comment: Ether - (1) Sometimes, it's not possible to change the legacy code (e.g. Powers That be get jitters from some cursed mess) and the only solution is to work around the problem; (2) While anyone *routinely* doing a hack like that deserves bad consequences, an approach like this, when VERY well documented and ideally end-of-lifed once no longer needed has its valid uses even in production environment. With great care. It still smells, I admit.

Comment: => the symlink solution will create one package with a bunch of subroutine redefined warnings, and could possibly cause errors in functionality.  This is because each will contain the same `package XXX;` line.